# NoClassDefFound error when using jUnit in Eclipse

Tags: java, junit, noclassdeffounderror

I have created a jUnit test class within Eclipse for Mac OS.  I was successfully able to create the class and run the code generated by Eclipse, but when I try to add another class I need into the file I get NoClassDefFound.

[image: NoClassDefFound]

It seems to be complaining about XmlPullParser, which is used in one of the methods I added:

```
@Test(expected= Exception.class) public void testParseNull() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException 
{ 
EntryParser parser = new EntryParser();
    parser.parse(null); 
}
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171726/noclassdeffound-error-when-class-definitely-exists) post but I don't think it is related.

Here is my build path:

[image: Java build path]

Comment: We need the code you're using to do that; it looks like you're trying to load classes over the network.

Comment: Can you possibly post a screenshot of your build path configuration tab from Eclipse?

Comment: What would cause classes to load over the network?  This class works fine in my project.  It just doesn't work in the jUnit-related class.

Comment: I added the build path snapshot.

Comment: I recently ran into this exception and it turns out for me it was because I had a huge stack trace and was running out of stack space. If your code makes a huge stack it could be the same issue, but from what you provided it doesnt seem that way.